# Showing that $\exp(rN_t-\lambda t(e^r-1))$ is a Martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, poisson-process

> Let $(N_t)_t$ be a homogeneous Poisson process with intensity
> $\lambda>0$. How can I prove that $Y_t=\exp(rN_t-\lambda t(e^r-1))$ is
> a Martingal w.r.t. the canonical filtration, $r\in \mathbb{R}$, $t\geq
> > 0$.

*My attempt*

- $Y_t$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t$ since $N_t$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t$ and $Y_t=f(N_t)$ is a measurable function of $N_t$.
- Integrability: $E(|Y_t|)<\infty$ ( I don't really see at first glance why that is the case)

For $0\leq s\leq t$, one has to show:$$E(\exp(rN_t-\lambda t(e^r-1))|\mathcal{F}_s)=\cdots = \exp(rN_s-\lambda s(e^r-1))$$

However, I don't know how to deal with the $\exp$ in $E(\cdot)$. It might be noteworthy that I know that $N_t-\lambda t$ (i. e. the compensated poisson process) and $(N_t-\lambda t)^2-\lambda t$ are martingales.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: $$N_t - N_s \sim \text{Poi}(\lambda(s-t))$$

And if $X$ is a Poisson random variable the MGF of $X$ is $$\mathbb E\left[e^{uX}\right] = e^{\lambda (e^u-1)}$$

Comment: Thanks, I see. What about the integrability?

Comment: @Analysis integrability it also follows from this answer, since $Y_t$ is positive (a.s.)

Comment: Thanks, I completed the proof.